# Crouching models putting character in strange position Unity Animation

Tags: unity-game-engine, animation, mixamo

When I try to animate crouching using blendtrees and animations imported from Mixamo, the character is put into a strange position where the lower half of their body under the "floor" and the legs scrunched up and going the wrong directions. Error message and the character in question attached.[Character model with legs going weird directions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/awMJT.png) [Error messages I received](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qF3OG.png)

I tried ensuring that the player was set to a humanoid rig.

Comment: It could be that you mappings are wrong right now. Is the file correct in Blender? You should try to import it in Blender and fix those animation issues.

Comment: im not sure how to do that

Comment: are you using unity animation rigging package. ?

Comment: It could be that your import setting is not proper. Trying different import setting could give you some idea what is happening.